# Stuck on Project Euler # 10

Tags: python

I'm very new to Algorithms and just started coding a while ago. Please help me out with [this problem from Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=10):

> The sum of the primes below 10 is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17.
>
> Find the sum of all the primes below two million.

I tried reading up about Sieve Algorithms and after understanding the concept implemented it.

```
def SieveofEratosthenes(n):
    prime = [True for i in range(n+1)]
    p = 2
    while(p*p <= n):
        if(prime[p] == True):
            for i in range(p*p, n+1, p):
                prime[i] = False
        p+=1 
        for p in range(2, n):
            if prime[p]:
                print(p),

#Driver Program
if __name__=='__main__':
    n=2000000
    print('Following are the prime numbers smaller than or equal to', n)
    SieveofEratosthenes(n)
```

The problem is that it's taking way too long. It took 7.8sec on my machine.
Plus how do I add all these numbers? What's the better way to handle it?

Comment: Double check your indentation. Is the `for p in range(2, n):` loop supposed to be inside the `while` loop?

Comment: Doesn't project euler have its own forum where people post solutions?

Comment: @HåkenLid Yes, there is a forum for each problem, but you have to enter the correct solution to get access to the forum.

Comment: Is the indentation correct? Why is the for loop inside the while loop? You should avoid redefining `p`.

Comment: input/output is much slower than pure arithmetic. You should avoid `print()` inside a loop. Only use print for debugging or for the final output. Return a list of primes and then finally `print(sum(sieve(n)))`

Comment: @HåkenLid Sure, I'll keep that in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer:

```
def SieveofEratosthenes(n):
    prime = [True for i in range(n+1)]
    p = 2
    while p*p <= n:
        if prime[p]:
            for i in range(p*p, n+1, p):
                prime[i] = False
        p += 1
    return prime


#Driver Program
if __name__=='__main__':
    n = 2000000
    print('Following is the sum of the prime numbers smaller than or equal to', n)
    primes = SieveofEratosthenes(n)
    sum_all = sum(p for p in range(2, n) if primes[p])
    print(sum_all)
```

It prompts:

```bash
>>> Following is the sum of the prime numbers smaller than or equal to 2000000
>>> 142913828922
```

## Some remarks

- Try to split functionality in the future: one function for getting the prime numbers and another for printing.
- In python, `if foo == True` could be written just like `if foo`

Comment: There are all kinds of optimizations of the sieve, but I will mention just this; after dealing with the 2s, there is no need to ever consider another even number.

Comment: Well, true indeed! Thanks